# StdOut value meanings from ZMQ pub/sub from GnuRadio?

Tags: python, byte, decode, zeromq, gnuradio

I am working with a remote source to get data from a 1MHz bandwidth. Once I have isolated a peak in the FFT plot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWlSe.png), I am sending that peak data through a ZMQ Pub Sink to a separate computer, where I decode the bytes into a string [using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uBwe.jpg). When I run the code, I get a series of numbers separated by periods. However, I don't know what the output numbers mean. Could anyone help me out with this? Thank you!!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdFjM.png) is a picture of the plain output from the low pass filter block and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNLIw.png) is the output when I push the peak detector data.

Comment: Please post the actual output.